# Index Match Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula in which I can search the sheet 'Judges' Assignments' to see what room a judge is assigned to and then return that value in the column next to the judge's name in the sheet 'All Judges.' I have tried index-match and hlookup formulas, but I cannot anything to work. Thank you so much for any help! I have an accessible view-only copy of the sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YJH-d7MtYcVd6EC06TVvmq5XP8bTRhwAVzTcxmvmKnE/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question is an exact copy of [Index Match Horizontally and Vertically](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/205065241). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 2):

Use `vlookup()` with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      A2:A, 
      { 
        'Judges'' Assignments'!B2:B, 'Judges'' Assignments'!A2:A; 
        'Judges'' Assignments'!E2:E, 'Judges'' Assignments'!A2:A; 
        'Judges'' Assignments'!H2:H, 'Judges'' Assignments'!A2:A 
      }, 
      2, false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See [vlookup() help page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318).

Comment: Your solutions are always simpler and more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

#### Formula

The formula creates an array of NULL values and room names assigned to the judge.  Then [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) converts the array to a single comma delimited text string while ignoring blank values.  While it is expected that a judge will only be assigned to one room, if more than one room is assigned by design or by error, they will al be listed in the results.

```
=BYROW(judgelist, LAMBDA(judge, IF(judge<>"", 
  TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, BYROW(assignments, LAMBDA(_row, 
    IF(INDEX(_row,,1)<>"",
       IFERROR(IF(MATCH(judge,_row,0),INDEX(_row,,1),)),)
    ))),
)))
```

###### Named Ranges

| Name | Reference | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **judgelist** | `'All Judges'!A2:A500` | Judge lookup list |
| **assignments** | `'Judges'' Assignments'!A2:J500` | Assignment date (rooms, judges etc.) |

###### Google Function Support

| [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) | [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) | [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) | [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)** | **[IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)** | **[MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)** |  |

[image]